# Using XQUERY (baseX) I want information inside some of Jasper reports. I need to return text inside ELEMENT cdata

Tags: xquery, cdata

using notepad++ I have the path to the element containing the cdata showing as this:

```
/jasperReport[1]/columnHeader[1]/band[1]/staticText[1]/text[1]
```

the source looks similar to this:

```
<jasperReport>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="22" >
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="48" height="20" uuid="one"/>
                <box leftPadding="1">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="8" />
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[MYNUM]]></text>
            </staticText>
```

I'm trying to use XQUERY to return values similar to "MYNUM" second to last line in xml fragment.
In this case it will tell me that this particular part of the header has the text "MYNUM" in it. I intend on returning more complete information for many similar reports using XQUERY with BaseX on my mac.

So I could run xquery on a set of report files that would output something like:

/filenameofreport.data

```
<Header>
<reportElement>x=0 y=0 value=MYNUM</reportElement>
<reportElement>x=10 y=0 value=THATNUM</reportElement>
</HEADER>
```

ok I know this input query:

```
declare namespace abc="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports";

for $document in collection("temp")
where document-uri($document) = "/temp/Daily_P1NoAssign_.data"
return
 for $thefield in  $document//abc:jasperReport[1]/abc:columnHeader[1]/abc:band[1]/abc:staticText[1]/abc:textElement[1]/abc:font
   let $fontsize := string-join(("<font>",$thefield/@size,"</font>"))
   let $docgroup := xs:string((document-uri($document)))
   group by $docgroup
   order by $docgroup
   return ( element {"jasperReport"} { $docgroup }  , $fontsize)
```

produced this output:

```
<jasperReport>/temp/Daily_P1NoAssign_.data</jasperReport>
<font>8</font>
```

So ... 
this input targeted the sibling of textElement should have the right element, but I don't know how to output the data

xquery:

```
declare namespace abc="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports";

for $document in collection("temp")
where document-uri($document) = "/temp/Daily_P1NoAssign_.data"
return
 for $thefield in  $document//abc:jasperReport[1]/abc:columnHeader[1]/abc:band[1]/abc:staticText[1]/abc:text[1]
   let $textinfo := string-join(("<text>",$thefield/*,"</text>"))
   let $docgroup := xs:string((document-uri($document)))
   group by $docgroup
   order by $docgroup
   return ( element {"jasperReport"} { $docgroup }  , $textinfo)
```

returns:

```
<jasperReport>/temp/Daily_P1NoAssign_.data</jasperReport>
<text></text>
```

update:
Oh I almost got it all figured out I think - first here is the solution so far, but I would like to output the data slightly differently...

```
declare namespace abc="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports";

for $document in collection("temp")
where document-uri($document) = "/temp/Daily_P1NoAssign_.data"
return
 for $thefield in  $document//abc:jasperReport[1]/abc:columnHeader[1]/abc:band[1]/abc:staticText/abc:text[1]
   let $textinfo3 := $thefield/text()
   let $docgroup := xs:string((document-uri($document)))
   group by $docgroup
   order by $docgroup
   return ( element {"jasperReport"} { $docgroup }  ,$textinfo3)
```

returns this with WONUM WORKTPE etc on separate lines:

```
<jasperReport>/temp/Daily_P1NoAssign_.data</jasperReport>
WONUM
WORKTYPE
LOCATION
MODELNUM
SERIALNUM
REPORTDATE
STATUSDATE
STATUS
OWNER
OWNERGROUP
WARRANTYEXPDATE
INWARRANTY
```

Is there a way to return this with WONUM WORKTYPE etc all on one line??

```
<jasperReport>/temp/Daily_P1NoAssign_.data</jasperReport>
WONUM WORKTYPE LOCATION MODELNUM SERIALNUM REPORTDATE STATUSDATE STATUS OWNER OWNERGROUP WARRANTYEXPDATE INWARRANTY
```

Comment: What is the question or issue?

Comment: I can’t seem to google my way to finding how to do this in xquery-or is it even possible.looking for such a query OR affirmation it is not possible in cquery

Comment: It's totally possible in XQuery. You would essentially just return that XPath. Depending upon how you are invoking the XQuery inside of BaseX, you might need the logic to select the doc (or docs) to run the expression against, but that same XPath can be used in an XQuery module to extract and return the same data.

Comment: Oh I almost got it all figured out I think - first here is the solution so far, but I would like to output the data slightly differently...

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to eliminate the linefeed characters would be to use the `normalize-space()` method.

Either

```
let $textinfo3 := normalize-space($thefield/text())
```

or

```
let $textinfo3 := normalize-space(string-join($thefield/text(), " "))
```

Comment: This won’t return the wonum on the same line- am I wrong? It is “parent” of all the field values found